# Getting all the values for a given key, in an array of objects, using JavaScript and/or D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm building a dashboard that uses D3.js for charts.  I have a large array of objects.  Each object has 32 key value pairs, with the same keys.  Doesn't anyone know a good way to get all the values for a given key?

EDIT:
As soon as I asked the question a simple function came to me.  Also thought maybe a function already existed that I wasn't finding.

```
function getValues(data, key){
  var values = [];

  data.forEach(function(d){
    var v = d[key];

    if(!d3.set(values).has(v)){
      values.push(v);
    }
  })

  return values;
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code, OP, so we might have a chance to help you. As it stands, this isn't a great question for SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is there a reason a basic for loop can't do the job for you? Recall the JavaScript arrays are associative, so you only need a single loop to go over each object. This means you don't need a second loop to go over all the keys within an object looking for the right key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have to create a lot of dashboards using D3 as well. Another option for you which I utilize a lot is underscore.js. It saves me time, and for my needs helps condense code. There is a function called 'pluck' in underscore, which does exactly what you asked for. For an array of objects, you can declare a key and it will return all values.

Example:

```
var data = [{name: 'dan', value: 40}, {name: 'ryan', value: 50}];
var getKeys = _.pluck(data, 'name');
=> ["dan", "ryan"]
```

http://underscorejs.org/#pluck

Comment: @user3226861 why do you add a library for such simple task ?

Comment: This should be downvoted. There's no need to add a utility to D3 for this. D3 has a keys function, which I've supplied as an answer.

Answer (score 13):

If you're already using d3, take a look at Mike Bostock's "Underscore Equivalents" gist: https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3934356

So

```
data.map(function(d) { return d[key]; });
```

will get you all the values. If you only want unique values, use

```
d3.set(data.map(function(d) { return d[key]; })).values());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `d3.keys()`:

```
d3.keys(data).filter(function(key) { return key })
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean `values` as simple primitive values -

You can use this altered code of myne (*which was originally used to flatten object actually*) - to find all the values for specific key (*recursive*) :

Example : for a **very** complex object , let's find all the values for a given key named "a"

```
var data ={a:5,g: [{"a":1,"b":[4,5,6,{a:55},[33, new Date()]]},{"c":2},{"a":3}]};

var g=[];

if (!Object.keys) { //not all browsers support it
    Object.keys = function (obj) {
        var keys = [],
            k;
        for (k in obj) {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, k)) {
                keys.push(k);
            }
        }
        return keys;
    };
}

function actualType(o)
{
  return Object.prototype.toString.apply(o);
}

var arr=actualType([]);
var obj=actualType({});

function work(a, val)
{
    if (actualType(a) == obj || actualType(a) == arr)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < Object.keys(a).length; j++)
        {
            if (Object.keys(a)[j] == val) g.push(a[Object.keys(a)[j]]);
            else
                work(a[Object.keys(a)[j]], val);
        }
    }
}

work(data,'a') //'a' is the value we're searching
console.log(g) //[5, 1, 55, 3]
```

http://jsbin.com/yofafove/1/edit

Comment: My objects are more simple, but that looks great for a more complex data set.

Comment: As I said , it was originally used in my proj to flatten objects. but i altered it for u . it can surely help you though.